# Alias a fully static class's reference within itself

Tags: python, reference, static-methods

Let's take the following piece of code as an example.

```
class StaticUtilities:

    @staticmethod
    def methodA():
        return 1

    @staticmethod
    def methodB():
        a = StaticUtilities.methodA()
        return a + 1
```

Is there any way that I can shorten the call to `methodA` within the same class?

If I was accessing this from another class I could use

```
import StaticUtilities as Utils

a = Utils.methodA()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `methodB` needs access to other attributes within the class (even if they are static methods), *it's not really static*. You can easily make it a class method, instead:

```
class StaticUtilities:

    @staticmethod
    def methodA():
        return 1

    @classmethod
    def methodB(cls):
        return cls.methodA() + 1
```

In use:

```
>>> StaticUtilities.methodB()
2
```